# Do LINQ to SQL dbml definitions store collation information?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, collation

Do LINQ to SQL dbml definitions store collation information?

I need to change the collation of a database and would like to know if I need to re-generate the dbml files to reflect this change.

Comment: well, you can open the dbml as xml and look inside ;), I don't remember seing that kind of information in dbml files.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL does not store collation in the DBML file ([LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)).

> **Restrictions/Difference from .NET**
>
> SQL uses collations to determine equality and ordering of strings. These can be specified on a SQL Server Instance, a database, a table column, or an expression.
>
> The translations of the functions implemented so far do not change the collation or specify a different collation on the translated expressions. So if the default collation is case-insensitive, functions like CompareTo or IndexOf can give results that differ from what the (case sensitive) .NET functions would give.